# How to display euro symbol (€) with symfony on centos server

Tags: twig, symfony, centos6

I use the symfony `MoneyType` field and the twig extension `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl` for display currencies. On my dev computer using Ubuntu, I can see the symbol € but on the prod server, using Centos 6, letters 'eur' are displayed.
I suppose it's due to a missing font, but which one? and how to install?

Comment: Did you run `composer require twig/extensions` on the PROD server?

Comment: Yes they are in the composer.json file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install this RPM:

https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.8/i386/Packages/iso-codes-3.16-2.el6.noarch.html

Not certain. Try it.

Edit #2.
In order to find it.
I tried this on my system:

`$ yum search iso-codes`

Which returns:

iso-codes-devel.noarch : Files for development using iso-codes
iso-codes.noarch : ISO code lists and translations

Thus you could try:

```
yum install iso-codes
```

and that might work. My repositories my be setup differently, but try the above command.

Comment: I've installed it and even cleared the cache and restarted httpd but it's still the same. Thanks